# How do i get the active ribbon tab name?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, excel-2007, ribbon, menubar

I have been searching the net for 2 days but found nearly nothing about this issue:

- How do I work with the **Ribbon (Menu)** in **Excel**?
- How do I get the active ribbon tab name?
- How do I select the **Home** or **Data** tab?

Comment: My understanding is that these things aren't possible. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: :) In programming nothing should be impossble

Comment: True, but they can be too much trouble to bother with :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tab-scaling feature was introduced with Office 2010. So, you need to use [Accessibility API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the required information (do whatever you need).

Comment: Hello, I remember your answers from other pages, you seem to know very much. You say 2010 and scaling and accessibility - isn't there some 2-3 lines code which returns the active ribbon tab for excel 2007 - like ribboncontrol.tab ?

Comment: No, Office 2007 doesn't provide anything for that. Accessibility API is the only way to go.

Comment: Tony Jollans did it for Word in VBA and it works perfect on his downloadable example.(http://www.wordarticles.com/Shorts/RibbonVBA/RibbonVBADemo.php) I tried to use the same code for VB but I always get an error for the IACCESSIBLE type variant. I state "Imports Accessibility" at the top but it still doesn't work.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2494267          nearly does the job, if only I could run it proper in my VS version