# Get names of tabs (not worksheets) in Excel Add In

Tags: c#, excel

I know of `this.RibbonUI.ActivateTabMso("some_tab")` to active tabs, but is there a way to view the available tabs in Excel code behind? I cannot find it in the docs or after digging through the Ribbon instance in the debugger.

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to a tab on the ribbon? Or are you trying to use a command from the ribbon?

Comment: No, I'm trying to see if a tab already exists. I simply need to get the name of the tab.

Comment: Maybe refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002606/how-do-i-get-the-active-ribbon-tab-name

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Accessibility API. It may do the trick. Thanks Wyatt.